# Data Version Control (dvc) cannot push to remote storage because querying cache

Tags: dvc

I am setting up a remote storage with dvc using webdavs

I can connect to the remote storage from Finder.

I added the new remote and I see it when I check (dvc remote list)

But when I try to push data, I have the request for password with 0% Querying cache

It stays 0% forever. And when I enter the password, it ends with the following error:

ERROR: unexpected error - No connection with LINK_OF_REMOTE_STORAGE

The only thing I am thinking about is how to check if I can connect to the server from dvc and why querying cache never ends (maybe never starts even)

Comment: So mounting from finder doesn't work at all? Are you able to connect to webdav in general?

Could you show `dvc version` output, please? Also, what webdav server are you using?

Also, please post full log for `dvc push -v` , it will help us understand the issue.



EDIT: moving to discord https://discord.com/channels/485586884165107732/485596304961962003/800653178018070598

Comment: Mounting from Finder works fine ...
DVC version: 1.11.10
 ERROR: failed to push data to the cloud - config file error: no remote specified. 
But I set up a storage. dvc remote list gives me a remote